# Boundedness of a Solution Operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $v \in L^2(\partial \Omega)$ and define $S(v) := y$ where $y$ satisfies $-\Delta y + y = 0 $ in $\Omega$ and $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \nu} = v$ on $\partial \Omega$. I need to show that $S$ is bounded in $L^2(\Omega)$ so that I can bound $(S(u)-y_0,S(v))$ with $y_0$ some $L^2$ function and ( , ) the $L^2$ inner product. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I am going to replace $v$ by $x$ because $v$ looks very similar to $\nu$. 
Let me mention some ideas. Note that some details may need tweaking. For instance, there is an implicit assumption that the boundary is sufficiently smooth.

So one idea would be to construct a bounded operator $E:L^2(\partial\Omega)\to L^2(\Omega)$ so that $\partial_\nu (Ex)=x$ on the boundary $\partial\Omega$. Then you define a new variable $u=y-Ex$. This $u$ has to satisfy the homogeneous Neumann condition on the boundary $\partial\Omega$, and $-\Delta u + u = \Delta Ex - Ex$ in the domain $\Omega$. Then use elliptic estimates to get 
$$
\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq c \|Ex\|_{L^2(\Omega)}.
$$
This, combined with the triangle inequality gives
$$
\|y\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq \|Ex\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+ \|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq c_1 \|x\|_{L^2(\partial\Omega)}.
$$

Another approach would be to employ the "standard elliptic theory", which says that the operator $T:H^{3/2}(\Omega)\to H^{-1/2}(\Omega)\times L^{2}(\partial\Omega)$ sending $y$ to the pair $(-\Delta y+y,\partial_\nu y)$ is a Fredholm operator of index zero. Since we know $T$ is injective, it is invertible, and by Banach's bounded inverse theorem, the inverse $T^{-1}$ is bounded. So we have the estimate
$$
\|y\|_{H^{3/2}(\Omega)} \leq c\|x\|_{L^{2}(\partial\Omega)},
$$
which is even better than an $L^2$-bound.

Comment: How might I go about constructing such an operator, my  first thought was the right inverse of the trace but I don't know if it will satisfy $\partial _{\nu} Ex = x$?

Comment: @user17904: You need to show that for Sobolev space $H$ of sufficient regularity the trace from $H$ to $L^2(\partial\Omega)$ has closed range. Than a bounded right-inverse exists by functional analysis. Typically, you can prove surjectivity, say, by partition of unity, smoothing and an explicit construction.

Answer (score 0):

Use the variational form of the problem with the specific test function y. Then using integration by parts we get that the $H^1$ norm squared is equal to the integral of S(v)v over the boundary. Finally tidy this up with trace theorem and cauchy-schwarz to obtain a bound.